# Maintain same imrect position at different resolution

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, resolution

I'm using the function `imrect`, to crop the ROI in image for further processing. I have two images to compare (imagine they are the same but with different resolution):

Image 1: 1024x1024 pixels and Image 2: 2000x2000 pixels. The pixel value is known, so I don't want to resize images. At first I select the ROI in the image 1, using the draggable rectangle:

```
imshow(image1);
h=imrect(gca,[10 10 200 200]); position=wait(h);
I=imcrop(image1,position);
```

Then I open `image2` which is the same image at different resolution. Now I need to calculate the position of `imrect` so it would cover the same ROI. The position of ROI in this image is different because of different resolution. So the position of the `imrect` should be different as well.

For `image2` I want to run a code like this, but I don't know how to estimate the position variable:

```
imshow(image2);
I2=imcrop(image2,unknown_position);
```

How can I estimate the position in `image2`?

Comment: there is no black magic involved. just apply the rule of three... you should really work on your maths skills if you want to do image processing...

Comment: how silly i was. thanks for clearing my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maths to the rescue!

```
x_2 = x_1 * width_2 / width_1
y_2 = y_1 * height_2 / height_1
```